# Is there a change of variables substitution that would allow this integral to be evaluated?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Is it known whether or not there exists a change in variable substitution that would allow the following integral to be evaluated?

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xyz}dxdydz$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antiderivative of this integrand is $\text{Li}_3(x y z)$ where appears the polylogarithm function. Using the bounds, the result is $\zeta (3)$.

This can be generalized to any number of variables $n$. For a product of six terms, the antiderivative will be $\text{Li}_6(u v w x y z)$ and the integral will be $\zeta (6)$.